# Powershell conditional replacement of a character sequence in a tab delimited file

Tags: regex, string, powershell, text, tabs

I would like to conditionally replace a character sequence from strings in a tab delimited file.

In the example below, I want to replace 'apple' with 'orange' when the character sequence starts with 'DEF'. 'xxx' can be any characters or any length (but unlikely to be 'DEF' or apple').

ie:

```
xxxDEFxapplexxx<tab>DEFxxxapplexxx<tab>xxxDEFxxxapplexxx
```

to:

```
xxxDEFxxxapplexxx<tab>DEFxxxorangexxx<tab>xxxDEFxxxapplexxx
```

Powershell script:

```
$fileName = "tabfile.txt"
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) |  
    Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match "^DEF")  { $_ -replace "apple", "orange"} else { $_ } } | 
    Set-Content -Path $fileName
```

It works fine when each string is separated by a new line (rather than a tab).
Output:

```
xxxDEFxxxapplexxx
DEFxxxorangexxx
xxxDEFxxxapplexxx
```

but doesn't work when the strings are separated by tabs (or spaces):
Output:

```
xxxDEFxxxapplexxx<tab>DEFxxxapplexxx<tab>xxxDEFxxxapplexxx
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the first character in regex is caret `^` that matches beginning of a line.

Comment: Not sure whether you want to keep the tabs in the output or not, but [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) does actually have a `-Delimiter` parameter: ``Get-Content -Path $fileName -Delimiter "`t" Encoding UTF8``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the comments by iRon and Thomas, I figured out something that works:

Split the string at the tabs to create an array:

`Get-Content` with `` -Delimiter "`t" ``  parameter.

Conditional match and replace text on each element:

`Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match "^DEF")  { $_ -replace "apple", "orange"} else { $_ } } |`

Recreate original string by joining each element of the array with a tab character:

`` Join-String -Separator "`t" ``

Complete code:

```
Get-Content -Path "tabfile.txt" -Delimiter "`t"|
Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match "^DEF")  { $_ -replace "apple", "orange"} else { $_ } } | 
Join-String -Separator "`t"|
Out-File "tabfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any conditional logic here because `-replace` does it for you implicitly: if there is no match, the string input is returned as is.

The regex you can use is

```
(?<=(?:^|\t)DEF_)apple
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Ct%29DEF_%29apple&i=ABC_apple%09DEF_apple%09GHI_apple%0D%0ADEF_apple%09ABC_apple%09GHI_apple&r=orange&o=m). Add `\b` word boundary if `apple` should not be followed with `_`, letter or digit, or add `(?![^\W_])` if it cannot be followed with a digit or letter, but can be followed with `_`.

*Details*:

- `(?<=(?:^|\t)DEF_)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a tab (`\t`) and `DEF_`
- `apple` - an `apple` string.

In Powershell, you could use

```
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) -replace "(?<=(?:^|\t)DEF_)apple", "orange" | Set-Content -Path $fileName
```